# Unable set inputAccessoryView toolbar in Pickerview

Tags: ios, uipickerview, toolbar, swift3

in swift 3, i am unable set toolbar in pickerview like

> pickerFilter?.inputAccessoryView = barAccessory

error is that inputAccessoryView is get-only property.

and When i am addsubview in Pickerview. toolbar is shown but done button not clickable

any solution?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: did you get the solution??

Comment: @tabassum let flexiblespace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem:.flexibleSpace , target: nil, action: nil)
        let btnDone = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(self.donePresed))
        let barAccessory = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: viewPicker.frame.size.width, height: 44))
        barAccessory.barStyle = .default
        barAccessory.isTranslucent = true
        barAccessory.items = [flexiblespace,btnDone]
        viewPicker.addSubview(pickerDrpDown!)
        viewPicker.addSubview(barAccessory)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
let flexiblespace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem:.flexibleSpace , target: nil, action: nil)

    let btnDone = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(self.donePresed))
    let barAccessory = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: viewPicker.frame.size.width, height: 44))
    barAccessory.barStyle = .default
    barAccessory.isTranslucent = true
    barAccessory.items = [flexiblespace,btnDone]

    viewPicker.addSubview(pickerDrpDown!)
    viewPicker.addSubview(barAccessory)
```

Comment: What's the pickerDrpDown ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are assigning `inputAccessoryView` to your `UIPickerView`, actually you should assign it to your relevant `textfield` not to `pickerview` it self!! Something like,

```
   textField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
```

Comment: What if i am not using textfield. i have to open PickerView on IBAction

Comment: means ? tell me your exact need!! you can't set `inputAccessoryView` to your `pickerView` itself!!

Comment: my requirement is clear. i am not able put toolbar with ok button on PickerView

Comment: set `yourTextField.inputAccessoryView = yourToolbar`, and you will get your tool bar with `ok` button! and set your `pickerView` as `inputView` of your `textField`

Comment: u can't get after this much communication.  i an mot using any textfield.

Comment: thats why i have said that `tell me your exact need`!! tell me how you want to show `pickerView` ? on button click? on tapgesture? and after selecting any data do you want to show it somewhere? or store somewhere ? or else?